# How often should I see "Refreshing due to a 401" and "Refreshing access_token"

Tags: google-drive-api

I have a Google App Engine task in task queue performing the following four steps on a file recently uploaded by my app to a Google Drive Account and new files created by resizing the original.

```
1- file = service.files().get(fileId=googleDriveFileId).execute()

2- resizedImage = resizeImage(theImage,currentWidth,currentHeight,135,90);
   newImage = putGoogleDriveFile(user,resizedImage,imageName,'image/jpeg',None,"image")

3- service.permissions().insert(fileId=file_id, body=new_permission).execute()

4- service.files().delete(fileId=googleDriveFileId).execute()
```

All the steps work, all the files are where they are supposed to be with correct permissions, etc.

However, my log files shows the access_token being refreshed for each step.

```
 URL being requested: https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/drive/v2/rest?userIp=0.1.0.2
2012-09-01 07:51:10.578 URL being requested: https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0Bx4nwQIkoY_7OVE4U3JtcUVPMzQ?alt=json
2012-09-01 07:51:10.602 Refreshing due to a 401
2012-09-01 07:51:10.602 Refresing access_token
2012-09-01 07:51:11.222 putting drive file
2012-09-01 07:51:11.231 have credentials
2012-09-01 07:51:11.232 URL being requested:  https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/drive/v2/rest?userIp=0.1.0.2
2012-09-01 07:51:11.478 URL being requested: https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=multipart&alt=json
2012-09-01 07:51:11.505 Refreshing due to a 401
2012-09-01 07:51:11.505 Refresing access_token
2012-09-01 07:51:13.676 setting permissions
2012-09-01 07:51:13.682 have credentials
2012-09-01 07:51:13.684 URL being requested: https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/drive/v2/rest?userIp=0.1.0.2
2012-09-01 07:51:13.777 URL being requested: https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0Bx4nwQIkoY_7dXhUbWdLaU9feUU/permissions?alt=json
2012-09-01 07:51:13.803 Refreshing due to a 401
2012-09-01 07:51:13.803 Refresing access_token
2012-09-01 07:51:14.484 have credentials
2012-09-01 07:51:14.485 URL being requested: https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/drive/v2/rest?userIp=0.1.0.2
2012-09-01 07:51:14.656 URL being requested: https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0Bx4nwQIkoY_7UUJadzNGa2oxRjA
2012-09-01 07:51:15.098 Refreshing due to a 401
2012-09-01 07:51:15.098 Refresing access_token
```

Is this what I should be expecting? It seems to me that one access_token for four actions running in one loop should suffice.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: I'm running into this as well. seems like the python api is refreshing the token, but not using the new access token in the request. So in my case it runs fine the first hour, but then fails once the original token expires. I see the same 'refreshing access_token' messages in my log, but the calls fail due to '403: User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile.'

Answer (score 1):

A typical access_token lasts for one hour. My guess is each request is still using the expired token instead of the shiny new one.